# GCC Plugins to inject enum declaration to the current compilation unit

Tags: c++, c, gcc, enums, gcc-plugins

Which is the best way to inject enum declarations to the current compilation unit in GCC? For example, I want to inject the enum global_ids:

```
#include <iostream>
/* Below enum to be injected by a GCC plugin */
enum global_ids {
    id_a = 0,
    id_b = 1,
    /* other IDs */
    id_z = 25
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Fifth enum ID has a value of " << id_e << std::endl;
}
```

Disclaimer: I am trying to learn about the GCC internals and want to use GCC plugins directly in my project, and will checkout MELT/GCC Python Plugins once I get a good understanding of the GCC internals.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the standard pattern of putting the enum into a header?

Comment: The plugin is called "preprocessor". `#include` your IDs.

Comment: The enum values are generated dynamically based on other function declarations in the compilation unit, and I don't want the programmer to create the enum by themselves. Hence the need for some compiler support via plugins. Also, (secondarily) this is an opportunity for me to learn more about GCC internals.

Comment: The dynamically generated stuff can be perfectly written into a file which is included before the compilation, and people are doing it. And if you want to learn about gcc internals - I believe there is a plenty of resources dedicated to it with examples.

Comment: But, a header file will be preprocessed _before_ the compilation. I want to be able to generate the enum values and the enum name _during_ the compilation. If I write the generated enum to a header file during compilation, the compiler will not be aware of the enum at all because the (presumably empty/stale) header will already have been preprocessed. 

I was not able to find this particular information regarding GCC internals anywhere online, and so I posted on Stack Overflow. Please point me to relevant examples if you know them  :-)